# using python to count unique values and scale by frequency

Tags: python, data-processing

I've got myself a dataset that looks like this:

```
[
    {'A':'0'},
    {'B':'0'}, 
    {'C':'1'}
]
```

I'd like to transmogrify it into a dataset that looks like this:

```
[
    {'0':'2'},
    {'1':'1'}
]
```

Essentially the task is counting the values,

and for each unique value

creating a new entry in a data-structure

for each one of those unique entries (once again, based on the values)

to increment the corresponding entry,

Basically the task is tallying up all of the times we've seen unique values and magnifying that by the number of times the value has been expressed.

What's the most efficient, effective way to do that in python?

I've been experimenting with counter but thus far without much success, as my base data structure seems to be incompatible, the codebase looks like this:

```
dict_hash_gas = list()
for line in inpt:
    resource = json.loads(line)
    dict_hash_gas.append({resource['first']:resource['second']})
```

and the dataset like this:

```
{"first":"A","second":"0","third":"2"} 
{"first":"B","second":"0","third":"2"} 
{"first":"C","second":"1","third":"2"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Counter` quite easily:

```
>>> data = [
...     {'A':'0'},
...     {'B':'0'},
...     {'C':'1'}
... ]
>>> import collections
>>> counts = collections.Counter(v for d in data for v in d.values())
>>> counts
Counter({'0': 2, '1': 1})
```

Now, to get the final list you want, simply:

```
>>> [{k:v} for k,v in counts.items()]
[{'0': 2}, {'1': 1}]
```

Although, I don't know why you would *want* such a list, I can only presume some REST-based API is expecting some JSON in that format...

Comment: nice- thanks a lot. as an aside- do you know why I print it to the console it always renders like this `Counter({u'0': 2, u'1': 1})`, i.e. with `Counter` written there? is it possible to further transform it into a normal dict?

Comment: also- would you recomend a particular way to turn this into a histogram?

Comment: @s.matthew.english because it is a *`Counter`*... no? If you want a regular dict, just use `dict(counts)`. Although really, why would you?

Comment: @s.matthew.english  do you mean, to *plot it*?

Comment: yes, precisely- i'd like to plot it as a histogram/bar chart

Comment: also, I'd like to somehow apply a threshold to it

Comment: @s.matthew.english you should ask another question for that, but you should probably do some research on different plotting libraries, for example, `matplotlib`

Answer (score 1):

```
result = dict()

for name, value in input.items():
    result.update({value: result.get(value, 0) + 1})
```

Comment: it doesn't work, presumably because I have a list of tuples- generates the following error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: Don't use `.update`, you create an intermediate dictionary that you immediately throw away. Just use `result[value] = result.get(value, 0) + 1`, or better yet, use `Counter` or `defaultdict` and ditch the call to `.get`